# How to install hotjar tracking to Yootheme Warp?

Tags: joomla, tracking, warp, hotjar

How to add the HotJar tracking code to YooTemplates? 
Although it's no longer a question for me, i thought maybe this could be of some help to others.

So, the recommended by hotjar documentation ''index.php file'' is not the appropriate file for adding the hotjar tracking code. Instead, i installed the code at

template/layouts/theme.php

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxLEA.png)  just before the '''' tag at the end of the file

I am not a programmer so maybe someone else has a better solution to suggest to help the community. So far it has worked fine for me for years.

Chears

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can even load it in a custom html module in the 'footer' position. Please try and let me know if it works. Then the community will have a second method to do it ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I had to delete the script to test some incompatibility issues. I’ll test your suggestion as soon as I return to hotjar. Maybe someone else will test it until then :)